# Faster method for searchsorted when both arrays are sorted

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, search

`numpy.searchsorted(a, v, ...)` basically finds the indices of the first elements in a **sorted array `a`** that are larger than or equal to the elements in v. I assume that this is faster than a method that does not take advantage of the fact that `a` is sorted.

Now what if `v` is also sorted? Certainly it should be possible to exploit this knowledge to make the algorithm faster? (Perhaps I'm wrong and the design of `searchsorted` makes this irrelevant; if so please excuse my question.)

So the question is: **What would be the fastest way to do the same as `searchsorted(a, v)` but for both `a` and `v` sorted?**

Comment: Have you got an example of `a` and `v` someone could play with?

Comment: (it's going to be pretty much irrelevant thought... unless `searchsorted` does some kind of near-by caching - )

Comment: @JonClements The specific data I'm working with might be difficult to transfer, but I'm asking more in general anyway, so any random (sorted) a and v would, ok. So e.g., `rng = np.random.default_rng()` `a = rng.random((10000,))*100` `a = np.sorted(a)` `v=rng.random((1000,))*100` `v = np.sorted(v)`. Something like this? (Or am I missing something important?)

Comment: @JonClements it doesn't have to be something with `searchsorted`, though. I'm just looking for some method that does the same as `searchsorted` and takes advantage of the fact that both `a` and `v` are sorted (and is thus faster than the normal `searchsorted(a,v)`).

Answer (score 2):

When `a` and `v` have approximately the same size, the best algorithm consist in merging the two arrays (see: [merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm)) (note you only need the indices and not the output merged array). This can be done in **linear time** (ie. `O(n+M)`) instead of a quasi-linear `O(n log M)` time.

Otherwise the problem can be solved in **`O(n log log M)` time** instead of `O(n log n)` time. This is only interesting if `a` is huge since `log M` is already quite small and one should be careful about *hidden constants* in algorithmic complexities. The algorithm is not trivial to implement. Here is the idea:

- Pick the middle value `v[k]` of `v` and split virtually `v` in two part (left and right ones)
- Perform a binary search of `v[k]` in `a` so to get its location `p`
- Now we can be sure that the items in the left part of `v` are located in `a[:p+1]` and the right part are in `a[p:]` (one side can be excluded in case of equality but let put this aside for sake of simplicity)
- Recursively apply the operation by calling `search(a[:p+1], v[:k])` and `search(a[p:], v[k+1:])`

Note that for the second algorithm, if `v` contains `i` multiple same values, then you can copy the location found `i` times and find a more strict lower/upper bound in `a` so to avoid degenerated case possibly resulting in a worse complexity.

Because of the CPython loop overhead and the one of Numpy function calls, this implementation needs to be implemented in native languages like C/C++ or in Cython or possibly using JITs like Numba.

Comment: Interesting. I was more hoping for a more practical method using some fast numpy methods or so that I could immediately use. But still interesting.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible directly in Numpy. This use-case is too specific to be directly implemented in Numpy and the benefit is too small in most cases to worse it (the Numpy code base is already quite big so adding too specific features causes maintainability issues). Alternative packages contains interesting similar methods like [sortednp](https://gitlab.sauerburger.com/frank/sortednp).

Comment: I would be surprised actually if this is such an uncommon problem as it is something I would expect occurs a lot when working with timeseries from different origins. But you might be right that the benefit may be too small.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I would assume that you could solve the problem thusly:

```py
def searchsorted_sorted(x, a):
    y = np.empty_like(a)

    l = 0
    for (i, s) in enumerate(a):
        pos = l + np.searchsorted(x[l:], s)
        y[i] = pos
        l = y[i]

    return y
```

So, you could use the knowledge  of v being ordered to restrict the search space for subsequent searches.

Since numpy likely uses binary search, the difference should be more pronounced when the values in `v` are cluttered towards the end of `a`. If you have a *large* number M of entries and only search for the indices of the last n, the second to n-th search restrict the length to be searched from M to M - n. Thus, rather than taking `O(n*log(M))` you would only need `O(n*log(n))`, which in theory makes a difference. Caveats:

1. Maybe `numpy` already does something similar?
2. Since `numpy` is implemented in C, it is not a fair comparison with this function (partly) written in python.
3. This implementation is rather cache-unfriendly, further reducing its usefulness.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking about a for loop, but was thinking it'd not be overly performant. Maybe I should try to time it.

Comment: @LuKas The idea is interesting but the enumerate-based loop will certainly make the code much slower because of the high overhead of `np.searchsorted` and the one of CPython loops. This overhead can be mitigated with a JIT like Numba for example.

Comment: @hfhc2 AFAIK Numpy do not do such an optimization because it does not check if the second parameter is sorted. How do you find a `O(n*log(n))` complexity? The complexity is left unchanged. In fact, if `a` contains `n` times the same value `min(x)`, then the binary search will be performed on the whole array so the complexity if still `O(n*log(M))`. The `O(...)` complexity must consider pathological cases (I also think the average cases have the same complexity).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Probably the worst case is impossible to do faster, even knowing that `v` is sorted, without any additional knowledge of the array. So indeed probably the big O cannot be lowered. Nonetheless, with the knowledge that `v` is sorted, it should at least be possible to improve the average case.

Comment: @LuKas I found two algorithms that have a lower complexity ;) . See my answer.

Comment: Well, I was trying to give an illustration to show that this improved version performs better than a "naive" one *under some circumstances*. If I restrict my analysis to these circumstances, the O-notation is applicable, even if just for these circumstances. In the general case, there is indeed no improvement...